# Line break in PHP Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little display problem on my project.

The fact is that I want to display some information (column types of an sql request `SHOW Columns` btw) in a table, but it does not display properly.

The code is :

```html
try
{
    echo '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb30 mt30">';
    echo'<thead>
            <th class="text-center">Name of column</th>
            <th class="text-center">Type</th>
            <th class="text-center">Update</th>
            <th class="text-center">Delete</th>
         </thead>';
    echo'<tbody>';
    $sql = $bdd->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table);
    $column_name = $bdd->query('select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = "'.$table.'" and table_schema = "'.$db_name.'" ');
    $i = 0;

    while($donnees = $column_name->fetch())
    {
        $column = $donnees[$i];
        echo '<tr><td class="col-db text-center">'.$donnees[$i].'</td>';
        while ($row = $sql->fetch())
        {
            echo '<td class="col-db text-center">'.$row["Type"].'</td>';
        }
        ?>
        <td><p class="text-center"><a href="form_update_table.php?database=<?php echo $db_name;?>&table=<?php echo $table;?>&column=<?php echo $column;?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></p></td>
        <td><p class="text-center"><a href="drop_column.php?database=<?php echo $db_name;?>&table=<?php echo $table;?>&column=<?php echo $column;?>" onclick="return confirm_delete()" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></p></td></tr>
        <?php
    }
    $i = $i + 1;
}
```

and the result is:

[image: The Resulting Image]

Unfortunately there is no `Line break` between the `"Types" ><`, how can I fix this?

I already tried a `<br/>`, it changed nothing.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Ps : a < br / > change Nothing* (my bad lol)

Comment: @NassimElHormi Problem is solve or not?

Comment: @PraveenKumar https://i.stack.imgur.com/80ysJ.png the informations doesn't have line break and I don't understand why

Comment: `$sql = $bdd->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table);` seems unnecessary

Comment: Where exactly is the line break?

Comment: @PraveenKumar In this code, there is no line break, I don't know how to put one in my table.

Comment: @RamRaider Ok thank you for your answer dude :) but can you explain me why please ?

Comment: @NassimElHormi - my bad, didn't notice the call to `$sql->fetch()` - please disregard the comment

Comment: @PraveenKumar he means that his code is creating the table in the wrong way with an invalid HTML so the columns and rows are not displayed as he expected. Dunno how to explain him that there is not such a linebreak feature for tables ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the second while. secon while is printing all type in a row. this is why you are having problem. if you just get one data in each of the circle in first loop, it will work ok

```
while($donnees = $column_name->fetch()) {
    $column = $donnees[$i];
    echo '<tr><td class="col-db text-center">'.$donnees[$i].'</td>';
    $row = $sql->fetch();
    echo '<td class="col-db text-center">'.$row["Type"].'</td>';
     ?>
    <td><p class="text-center"><a href="form_update_table.php?database=<?php echo $db_name;?>&table=<?php echo $table;?>&column=<?php echo $column;?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></p></td>
    <td><p class="text-center"><a href="drop_column.php?database=<?php echo $db_name;?>&table=<?php echo $table;?>&column=<?php echo $column;?>" onclick="return confirm_delete()" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></p></td></tr>
<?php
}
```

Comment: happy to help.. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
try
{
    echo '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb30 mt30">';
    echo'<thead>
            <th class="text-center">Name of column</th>
            <th class="text-center">Type</th>
            <th class="text-center">Update</th>
            <th class="text-center">Delete</th>
         </thead>';
    echo'<tbody>';
    $sql = $bdd->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table);
    $column_name = $bdd->query('select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = "'.$table.'" and table_schema = "'.$db_name.'" ');
    $i = 0;

    while($donnees = $column_name->fetch())
    {
        $column = $donnees[$i];
        while ($row = $sql->fetch())
        {
            echo '<tr><td class="col-db text-center">'.$donnees[$i].'</td><td class="col-db text-center">'.$row["Type"].'</td><td><p class="text-center"><a href="form_update_table.php?database='.'$db_name.'&table='.$table.'&column='.$column.'" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></p></td>
        <td><p class="text-center"><a href="drop_column.php?database='.$db_name.'&table='.$table.'&column='.$column.'" onclick="return confirm_delete()" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></p></td></tr>';
        }
        ?>

        <?php
    }
    $i = $i + 1;
```

Comment: there is a problem in this line :  echo '<tr><td class="col-db text-center">'.$donnees[$i].'</td><td class="col-db text-center">'.$row["Type"].'</td><td><p class="text-center"><a href="form_update_table.php?database='.'$db_name.'&table=<?php echo $table;?>&column='.$column.'" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></p></td>

Comment: with the &table i cant get it that's why i can't launch the code

Comment: Corrected that please try now

Answer (score 0):

Could this help?

```
try
{
    echo '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb30 mt30">';
    echo'<thead>
            <th class="text-center">Name of column</th>
            <th class="text-center">Type</th>
            <th class="text-center">Update</th>
            <th class="text-center">Delete</th>
         </thead>';
    echo'<tbody>';

    $column_name = $bdd->query('select column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name = "'.$table.'" and table_schema = "'.$db_name.'" ');

    while($donnees = $column_name->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $column = $donnees['column_name'];
        echo '<tr><td class="col-db text-center">'.$donnees['column_name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="col-db text-center">'.$donnees['data_type'].'</td>';

        ?>
        <td><p class="text-center"><a href="form_update_table.php?database=<?php echo $db_name;?>&table=<?php echo $table;?>&column=<?php echo $column;?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></p></td>
        <td><p class="text-center"><a href="drop_column.php?database=<?php echo $db_name;?>&table=<?php echo $table;?>&column=<?php echo $column;?>" onclick="return confirm_delete()" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></p></td></tr>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using mysqli?